# python: importing an object appears to inconsistently clobber an existing object?

Tags: python, python-import

So this started as a question about importing data objects via the import command, and I'm aware of things like pickle and json and all sorts of other ways to do this that may well be better options, but in trying to get my brain around this I found a behavior that I'm sure has logic behind it, but I can't figure out what that logic is.  So I'll demonstrate with a super simple example...

I have a file named "toimport.py" consisting only of a dictionary definition:

```
foo = {
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2",
   "key3" : "value3",
}
```

Below, I run a simple series of commands:

First, create a dictionary named "bar" and assign a key/value pair to it.

Second, import the dictionary in my "toimport" file.  I wasn't sure whether the import would clobber the value of the existing key, it appears that it does:

```
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf2, Oct 24 2018, 15:53:56) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

 >>> bar = {"key1":"blue"}
 >>> print (bar)
{'key1': 'blue'}

 >>> from toimport import foo as bar
 >>> print (bar)                
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

OK, so I guess that's how Python's import works.  No problem.  ;-)  But... if I change one of the values in the dict, and then run the exact same import command... this time it does NOT clobber the value that I set earlier:

```
>>> bar['key1'] = 'zoomie'
>>> print (bar)           
{'key1': 'zoomie', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}

>>> from toimport import foo as bar
>>> print (bar)                
{'key1': 'zoomie', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

I'm sure there's a perfectly sensible explanation for this, but I can't begin to figure it out on my own.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"Clobbering" is not the right way to think about this. As always, with Python variables you should think about *names*.

You first define a dictionary with the name "bar". Then, you say "import the foo dict from toimport and assign it the name bar". So, this reassigns "bar" to point at the dictionary in toimport.

Next, you modify the dictionary. Don't forget, names point at objects, so changing the value of one of the keys in "bar" means that that value will change *everywhere* that that dictionary is referenced. If you had also imported the foo dict somewhere else, that reference would also see the change.

So, the second time you import foo as bar, it is effectively a no-op; you changed it in both places, so there is no modification to be made. "bar" is already a reference to the same dictionary, and importing it again makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.  Following up: if I *wanted* behavior such that any time it was "re-imported" it would overwrite what else was there - what would be a mechanism for doing that?  (And yes, I realize it's likely not called 'import' but didn't have a better verb handy...)

Comment: Well the only way for that to work would be to avoid modifying the original dict. So instead of your import...as, you could do `from toimport import foo; bar = copy.deepcopy(foo); del foo`.